# F# + xUnit - what could possibly go wrong

Tags: f#, xunit

I've just literally hit a brick wall trying to configure F# 4.5.0.0 under VS 15.8.1 to run xUnit tests. Here is the repo with the issue: https://github.com/kkkmail/fSharp-xUnit .
When I try to run all tests, VS comes back with this message: No test is available in C:\GitHub\fSharp-xUnit\DummyApp\DummyApp\bin\Debug\DummyApp.exe C:\GitHub\fSharp-xUnit\DummyApp\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll C:\GitHub\fSharp-xUnit\DummyApp\DummyApp\DummyApp.fsproj C:\GitHub\fSharp-xUnit\DummyApp\Tests\Tests.fsproj. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Both the "DummyApp" and tests were created from scratch using VS and I cleared all temp files and all nuget caches prior to creating the solution as advised in various places on the web.

Comment: Add `xunit.runner.visualstudio` to your test project

Comment: @CaringDev Thanks a lot. That worked. Could you, please, add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** Add [`xunit.runner.visualstudio`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio/) to your test project.

---

For discovering tests Visual Studio relies on its test runner. This test runner can discover / run all tests for testing frameworks which implement the corresponding adaptor interfaces [`ITestDiscoverer`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/master/src/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel/Adapter/Interfaces/ITestDiscoverer.cs) and [`ITestExecutor`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/master/src/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel/Adapter/Interfaces/ITestExecutor.cs). For xUnit, these interfaces are implemented in [`VsTestRunner`](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.runner.visualstudio/VsTestRunner.cs) which is published in [`xunit.runner.visualstudio`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio/).

See also the [xUnit docs about running tests in VS](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop#run-tests-visualstudio)